# Additional text boxes return old value, how do I make my textboxes blank?

Tags: html, angularjs, textbox

I have made text boxes for my website using Angular, users have an option to add more information by clicking a button that gives them another group of text boxes to fill in. However, when this happens the new text boxes appear with the previous information I filled in. I want the additional text boxes to be blank as they were with the first set, but I am not sure how to achieve this.

```
    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$ctrl.closeInfoModel()">&times;</button>
    <h5 class="title">Add Details</h5>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ng-form name="detailsForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Client Details:
                &nbsp;<a data-ng-show="!$ctrl.isEditingDetails && !$ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails"
            data-ng-click="$ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails = true"><i class="tools-plus fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <span data-ng-show="$ctrl.isEditingDetails || $ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails">
            <a title="Save" data-ng-click="$ctrl.saveDetails(detailsForm.$valid)" ><i class="tools-plus fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a title="Saving" ng-if="$ctrl.isSavingDetails"><i class="tools-plus fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            &nbsp;
            <a title="Cancel" data-ng-click="$ctrl.stopEditingOrAdding()"><i class="tools-plus fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </span></h5>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <table class="table" ng-if="$ctrl.clientDetails.length == 0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Desired Amount</b></td>
                            <td><b>Credit Limit</b></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td ng-if="$ctrl.isEditingDetails && !ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails">
                                <input name="desiredAmount" ng-model="$ctrl.inputDesiredAmount" type="text" class="form-control"
                                  yl-account-address-text ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="30">
                                    <div data-ng-click="$ctrl.deletedesiredAmount()"></div></td>
                            <td ng-if="$ctrl.isEditingDetails && !ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails">
                                    <input name="creditLimit" ng-model="$ctrl.inputCreditLimit" type="text" class="form-control"
                                      yl-account-address-text ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="30">
                                    <div data-ng-click="$ctrl.deleteCreditLimit()"></div></td>
                                  </tr>
                             </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <table class="table" ng-if="$ctrl.clientDetails.length > 0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Desired Amount</b></td>
                                    <td><b>Credit Limit</b></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="criteria in $ctrl.clientDetails">
                                    <td ng-if="!$ctrl.isEditingDetails">{{criteria.desiredAmount}}</td>
                                    <td ng-if="$ctrl.isEditingDetails && !ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails">
                                        <input name="desiredAmount" ng-model="$ctrl.inputdesiredAmount" type="text" class="form-control"
                                        yl-account-address-text ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="30">
                                        <div data-ng-click="$ctrl.deletedesiredAmount()"></div></td>
                                        <td ng-if="!$ctrl.isEditingDetails">{{criteria.CreditLimitLimit}}</td>
                                    <td ng-if="$ctrl.isEditingDetails && !ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails">
                                            <input name="creditLimit" ng-model="$ctrl.inputCreditLimit" type="text" class="form-control"
                                            yl-account-address-text ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="30">
                                            <div data-ng-click="$ctrl.deleteCreditLimit()"></div></td>
                                          </tr>
                                     </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table class="table" ng-if="$ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails">
                                    <thead>
                                    </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input name="desiredAmount" ng-model="$ctrl.inputdesiredAmount" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                    yl-account-address-text ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="30">
                                                    <div data-ng-click="$ctrl.deletedesiredAmount()"></div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                        <input name="creditLimit" ng-model="$ctrl.inputCreditLimit" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                        yl-account-address-text ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="30">
                                                        <div data-ng-click="$ctrl.deleteCreditLimit()"></div></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

**Component file**

All references to the function that adds text boxes are below, I set `addingAnotherSetOfDetails` to false in the component controller

```
public stopEditingOrAdding(): void {
    this.isEditingDetails = false;
    this.addingAnotherSetOfDetails = false;
}

  public saveDetailsForClients(isFormValid: boolean): void {
     if (!isFormValid) {
        return;
     }
     let clientDetails = new app.domain.detailsCriteriaModel(this.inputDesiredAmount, this.inputCreditLimit);
     this.detailsCriteria.push(clientDetails);
     this.isEditingDetails = false;
     this.addingAnotherSetOfDetails = false;
   }
```

Comment: Please add javascript code as well.

Comment: I have added the functionality stuff now

Comment: where are you changing value of this $ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails to true?

Comment: I am changing the value of $ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails in the html

Comment: In this line I set it to true:  data-ng-click="$ctrl.addingAnotherSetOfDetails = true"><i class="tools-plus fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

Comment: Please see this is this you are trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/yjkmgsn6/ If not please create a fiddle and we can see whats wrong with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Yes,  I can see with the fiddle the new text boxes generated with the 'add more' button creates blank text boxes which is what I want :)

Comment: Try to embrace the angular way of doing things this way your code wont be messed up. Its gonna b easily manageable. Glad it helped you :) cheers.